# How do I store 5 variable input values in one variable in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, redux

I have 5 different inputs for taking OTP. and I am using 6 `useState` hook to get their value.

Now I want to store those 5 input value in the 6th variable I'm passing to my redux store. 
I tried this way but it returns an object and also use `parseInt` but it doesn't work.

```
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState(null);
  const [digitOne, setDigitOne] = useState(null);
  const [digitTwo, setDigitTwo] = useState(null);
  const [digitThree, setDigitThree] = useState(null);
  const [digitFour, setDigitFour] = useState(null);
  const [digitFive, setDigitFive] = useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const otp = { digitOne, digitTwo, digitThree, digitFour, digitFive };
    console.log(digitOne, digitTwo, digitThree, digitFour, digitFive);
    dispatch(checkVerification({ user_info, otp })).then(() => {
      console.log(otp);
    });
  }; 

return (

   <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        className="flex flex-col justify-start w-full mt-lg "
      >
        <div className="flex flex-row justify-between mx-auto max-w-screen-xs space-x-2">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="text-xl w-10 text-center bg-transparent  border-t-0 border-l-0 border-r-0 focus:ring-0 focus:border-gray-400 border-b border-gray-400 h-10 "
            pattern="[0-9]"
            maxLength={1}
            value={digitOne}
            onChange={(e) => setDigitOne(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="text-xl w-10 text-center bg-transparent  border-t-0 border-l-0 border-r-0 focus:ring-0 focus:border-gray-400 border-b border-gray-400 h-10 "
            pattern="[0-9]"
            maxLength={1}
            value={digitTwo}
            onChange={(e) => setDigitTwo(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="text-xl w-10 text-center bg-transparent  border-t-0 border-l-0 border-r-0 focus:ring-0 focus:border-gray-400 border-b border-gray-400 h-10 "
            pattern="[0-9]"
            maxLength={1}
            value={digitThree}
            onChange={(e) => setDigitThree(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="text-xl w-10 text-center bg-transparent  border-t-0 border-l-0 border-r-0 focus:ring-0 focus:border-gray-400 border-b border-gray-400 h-10 "
            pattern="[0-9]"
            maxLength={1}
            value={digitFour}
            onChange={(e) => setDigitFour(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="text-xl w-10 text-center bg-transparent  border-t-0 border-l-0 border-r-0 focus:ring-0 focus:border-gray-400 border-b border-gray-400 h-10 "
            pattern="[0-9]"
            maxLength={1}
            value={digitFive}
            onChange={(e) => setDigitFive(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button className="uppercase flex-grow mt-6 p-2 bg-red-500 text-white px-4 rounded mx-lg">
          proceed
        </button>
      </form>

);
```

Actions

```
import ApiInstance from "../../Api/root";
import store from "../store";
import { CHECK_VERIFIED } from "../Types/CustomerVerificationTypes";
import {
  CUSTOMER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  GET_CUSTOMER_LOGIN,
} from "../Types/CustomerLoginTypes";

export const checkVerification =
  ({ user_info, otp }) =>
  async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const deviceId = getState().device.device.data.device.id;
    localStorage.setItem("id", deviceId);
    console.log(otp);
    const res = await ApiInstance.get(
      `customers/otp/verification?mobile_number=${user_info.mobile_number}&country_code=${user_info.country_code}&otp=${otp}&device_id=${deviceId}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      }
    )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Auth Token", res.data);
        dispatch({
          type: CHECK_VERIFIED,
          payload: res.data,
        });

        // todo only if API Call is success
        if (res.data.success) {
          localStorage.setItem("authToken", res.data.token);
        } else {
          alert("Entered OTP is wrong, Try Again");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

Also I've set `maxLength` of input to 1 but How do I move one input to another after user puts a number?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this `const otp = { digitOne, digitTwo, digitThree, digitFour, digitFive };`? It's a little unclear what you are asking for, or if there's an issue.

Comment: @DrewReese sorry about that. Yes I want to store those value in just one variable which is otp here. I can't do this with my approach because it return an object.

Comment: What returns an object? `otp`? Of course`otp` an object, that's how you pack variables into a single object. Are you needing to unpack the values in your async action or some reducer?

Comment: Yes I want to unpack the values and pass it to my actions.
In my API I want pure numbers

Comment: I see, can you update your question to include all the code you're trying to handle this `checkVerification` action?

Comment: sure, give me sec.

Comment: BTW, to "unpack" the object properties, use destructuring assignment, i.e. `const { digitOne, digitTwo, digitThree, digitFour, digitFive } = otp`.

Comment: right but it will just say assigned a value but never used

Comment: ***What*** will say assigned a value but never used? Please try to fully explain what it is that you are trying to do, and include any error/warning messages up front.

Comment: If I use `const { digitOne, digitTwo, digitThree, digitFour, digitFive } = otp`
It just says these five variables are assigned but never used. just a warning.Then if I submit the OTP it gives me an error of

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'digitOne' of 'otp' as it is null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234953/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-random-18).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add The Following Code To Move A The Curosor To Next Input After Adding A Input. Please Validate Cause it will take some time to reproduce and test the answer. anywas you can do this by using the `.focus()` function on the element.:

```
 const [otp, setOtp] = useState(null);
  const [digitOne, setDigitOne] = useState(null);
  const [digitTwo, setDigitTwo] = useState(null);
  const [digitThree, setDigitThree] = useState(null);
  const [digitFour, setDigitFour] = useState(null);
  const [digitFive, setDigitFive] = useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const otp = { digitOne, digitTwo, digitThree, digitFour, digitFive };
    console.log(digitOne, digitTwo, digitThree, digitFour, digitFive);
    dispatch(checkVerification({ user_info, otp })).then(() => {
      console.log(otp);
    });
  }; 

return (

   <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        className="flex flex-col justify-start w-full mt-lg "
      >
        <div className="flex flex-row justify-between mx-auto max-w-screen-xs space-x-2">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="text-xl w-10 text-center bg-transparent  border-t-0 border-l-0 border-r-0 focus:ring-0 focus:border-gray-400 border-b border-gray-400 h-10 "
            pattern="[0-9]"
            maxLength={1}
            value={digitOne}
            onChange={(e) => {
    setDigitOne(e.target.value)
    document.getElementById('digitTwo').focus()
            }}
            id="digOne"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="text-xl w-10 text-center bg-transparent  border-t-0 border-l-0 border-r-0 focus:ring-0 focus:border-gray-400 border-b border-gray-400 h-10 "
            pattern="[0-9]"
            maxLength={1}
            value={digitTwo}
            id="digitTwo"
            onChange={(e) => {
    setDigitTwo(e.target.value)
    document.getElementById('digitThree').focus()
            }}

          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="text-xl w-10 text-center bg-transparent  border-t-0 border-l-0 border-r-0 focus:ring-0 focus:border-gray-400 border-b border-gray-400 h-10 "
            pattern="[0-9]"
            maxLength={1}
            value={digitThree}
    id="digitThree"
            onChange={(e) => {
    setDigitThree(e.target.value)
    document.getElementById('digitFour').focus()
            }}
    enter code here
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="text-xl w-10 text-center bg-transparent  border-t-0 border-l-0 border-r-0 focus:ring-0 focus:border-gray-400 border-b border-gray-400 h-10 "
            pattern="[0-9]"
            maxLength={1}
            value={digitFour}
    id="digitFour"
           onChange={(e) => {
    setDigitFour(e.target.value)
    document.getElementById('digitFive').focus()
            }}
    enter code here
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="text-xl w-10 text-center bg-transparent  border-t-0 border-l-0 border-r-0 focus:ring-0 focus:border-gray-400 border-b border-gray-400 h-10 "
            pattern="[0-9]"
            maxLength={1}
            value={digitFive}
           id="digitFive"
            onChange={(e) => {
    setDigitFIve(e.target.value)
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <button className="uppercase flex-grow mt-6 p-2 bg-red-500 text-white px-4 rounded mx-lg">
          proceed
        </button>
      </form>

);
```

Please Mark It As Correct If It Works!

Kamestart

Comment: Hi, Please See This Answer. If It Does not work pls inform. i will delete it.

Comment: Thank you but it'll still return a string.

Comment: Yes That Will Happen, Scince You Have kept the input type to text in the input fields. turn it to Number and set the min and max attributes. then plese mark as correct. example <input type="Number" min="0" max="9">. This Will Do The Trick

Comment: let me check that. Thanks

Comment: I did that still returns a string.

Comment: Can You Plese Share Your Code Now With A pOstbin Link Or Something?

Comment: Sorry But If It Returns A String Use The ParseInt Function which converts a string into a number. Before Sumbmitting the form

Comment: It won't work. project is a bit large. but you could copy my code most of it'll work. not the redux part obviously

Comment: I did use parseInt but it still throws me an error, also since I'm using it like this `    const otp = { digitOne, digitTwo, digitThree, digitFour, digitFive };` it gives me and output of 1 1 1 1 1 like with spaces you know. That's why it's not wokring

Comment: Im Sorry For The Postbin comment.  Please Refer to the Parse int comment

Comment: so when you are submitting the form why dont you do ``` const finalOtpNum = ParseInt(digitOne + digitTwo + digitThree + digitFour + digitFive)?

Comment: won't that be a sum of those variables?

Comment: No. Scince It Is Currently In A String State It WIll combine the digits. the use ParseInt. Just Try It.

Comment: Let me try that. will get back in a min.

Comment: Hi, are you on social media or twitter or something I would to connect, I ran into these kind of situation all the time and I could share these questions with you.

Comment: No, I dont. but i do have mail, github and stackoverflow accounts. i know this is off topic but if you need any pls ask here in the comments itself

Comment: okay, I'll just message you here. Thanks. Have a great day ahead

Comment: Im Sorry But where will you message? I dont understand. i sort of sont explore stackoverflow features so much.

Comment: In the comments, is that alright?

Comment: Yes. It Is FIne. I am Sorry i did not see.

Comment: can you help me mate?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68439829/why-am-i-getting-typeerror-cannot-read-property-push-of-undefined-react-route