# Why am I getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm just checking if I have language in redux store or not. If I have, I'll save that in my `localStorage`, if not I want to navigate to a component call `MultiLanguage`. 
I used below approach using `history` but it's showing mw an error. What is it showing push of `undefined` and what could be solution for this?

```
const history = useHistory();
  const language = store.getState().languages.selectedLangauge.language;
  console.log("language", language);
  if (language) {
    localStorage.setItem("language", language);
  } else {
    history.push("/multilanguage");
  }
  return (
    <div className="font-metropolis_regular">
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Selection} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/home" component={Homepage} />
        <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
        <Route path="/multilanguage" component={MultiLanguage} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: History is undefined.

Comment: one mistake is use switch as wrapper of all route https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch

Comment: [You can't use a router hook outside of the actual router.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64838587/how-to-properly-use-usehistory-from-react-router-dom)

Comment: @AvaniBataviya Now, I added the Switch, but still getting error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason is simple, as the error says, your `useHistory` hook returns undefined. This happens because this hook can only be called inside a component wrapped by `Router` so the decision might be moving it one level up.
Take a look at this for code examples https://flaviocopes.com/react-router-uselocation-usehistory-undefined/